# Symfony 3 mulitipe firewalls + HWIAouthBundle + UsernamePasswordToken

Tags: symfony, hwioauthbundle

Hi i'll to authenticate the user programmatically,

```
    $user = new User();
    $user->setStatus(9);
    $user->setUsername('Gast_'.++$id);
    $user->setPassword('0');
    $user->setEmail('Gast_'.$id.'@');
    $user->setAvatar('avatar.jpg');
    //create role
    $ur = $this->em()->getRepository('AppBundle:UserRole')->findOneBy(array('role'=>'ROLE_USER'));//new UserRole();
    $user->addUserRole($ur);        
    //login as Guest automatically
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'guest', $user->getRoles());
    $this->get('security.token_storage')->setToken($token);
    $this->get('session')->set('_security_main', serialize($token));
```

User Class ->

```
class User extends OAuthUser implements AdvancedUserInterface, \Serializable
```

security.yml

```
# app/config/security.yml
```

security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\User: plaintext

```
role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_EDITOR]

providers:
    chain_provider:
        chain:
            providers: [user_db, hwi_oauth]
    user_db:
        entity: { class: "AppBundle:User" }
    hwi_oauth:
        id: ib_user.oauth_user_provider 

firewalls:
    socials:
        pattern: ^/
        anonymous: true
        http_basic: ~
        # provider: user_db
        switch_user: true
        form_login:
            provider: user_db
            login_path: /lgn
            check_path: /lgn
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path: /.*
        oauth:
            resource_owners:
                facebook:       "/login/check-facebook"
            login_path:        /lgn
            use_forward:       false
            failure_path:      /reg
            default_target_path: /
            oauth_user_provider:
                service: ib_user.oauth_user_provider 
                #hwi_oauth.user.provider.entity
    guest:
        pattern: ^/guest
        provider: user_db
        anonymous: ~
        http_basic: ~
        form_login:
            login_path: /guest/lgn
            check_path: /guest/lgn
            use_referer: true
        logout:
            path: /logout
            target: /
        remember_me:
            secret:   '%secret%'
            lifetime: 604800 # 1 week in seconds
            path: /.*
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

access_control:
      - { path: ^/admin/user.*, roles: ROLE_SUPER }
      - { path: ^/admin, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }          
      - { path: /.*, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

Wenn the code with programmatically authentication is done without error, but if i go to another page, i get the following error ->

```
Neither the property "id" nor one of the methods "id()", "getid()"/"isid()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "HWI\Bundle\OAuthBundle\Security\Core\User\OAuthUser".
```

Why `UsernamePasswordToken($user, null, 'guest', $user->getRoles())` does not use my guest-firewall?
Any ideas? Or do u need more info?

Comment: regarding the documentation ( [here](http://api.symfony.com/3.2/Symfony/Component/Security/Core/Authentication/Token/UsernamePasswordToken.html) ) third parameters must be provider key not firewall key.

Comment: I've tried to use "user_db" as provider-key, but now I can't authenticate the "Guest-User"

Comment: try like that `new UsernamePasswordToken($user, $user->getPassword(), 'guest', $user->getRoles());`

Comment: it does not help, only one thing helps, if i remove the whole block "socials:" and it remailns only "guest", then it works, without password ;-) but block socials I need for FaceBook :)